# Counting binary words distance one from codewords

Tags: coding-theory

If you have a [15,11] hamming code, how would you count the number of binary words that are distance 1 from codewords?

I know this code will have 2048 codewords, and there are 32768 binary words of length 15.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: imagine $x$ is one of the 2048 codewords. How many words there are that are at distance 1 from that $x$?

Hint 2: Suppose $z$ is at distance 1 from $x$. Is it possible that $z$ is another codeword? Is is possible that $z$ is at distance 1 from another codeword?

Comment: 30720 words at distance one (15 for each codeword), z cannot be a codeword as hamming codes have minimum distance 3.... am I close?!

Comment: Yes. You only need to answer the last question to assert that you are not counting duplicates, and that $15\times 2048$ is the right answer.

Comment: I don't think that z can be distance 1 from a codeword, but I don't know why...

Comment: Ok... if z is distance one from x, it cannot be distance 1 from another code word, say y, as then x and y would be distance 2, which they can't be because the minimum distance between codewords is 3.